# Sum up the second value from one dictionary with all values from another dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.6

I have two dictionaries, with the same keys, but different values. I want to make a new dictionary with all values from dictionary1 to be summed up with the second value of dictionary2.

```
input:
dic1 = { 'ENST1' : [ 33, 55, 66, 77 ], 'ENST2' : [ 55, 32, 45 ] }
dic2 = { 'ENST1' : [ 'abc', 100, 200 ], 'ENST2' : [ 'cdg', 200, 300 ] }

output:
dic3 = { 'ENST1' : [ 133, 155, 166, 177 ] , [ 'ENST2' : 255, 232, 245 ] }
```

I'm using python 3.6.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you've already tried?

Comment: Your values don't add up though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. For future if anyone needs the answer, this did the job:

```
for key in dic1:
    for i in range(0,len(dic1[key])):
        if len(dic1[key]) > 0:
            dic1[key][i] = dic1[key][i] + dic2[key][1]
```

I have overwritten directly dic1, if that was not desired then I could make a copy of dic1 into dic3 and do this on the last line:

```
dic3[key][i] = dic1[key][i] + dic2[key][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This version would also work:

```
dic3 = {}

for (k,v), (k2,v2) in zip(dic1.items(), dic2.items()):
    dic3[k] = [x+y for x, y in zip(v, v2)]
```